# Python None value not applied

Tags: python, boto

I'm trying to look for keys and values in an AWS instance. If the key is present I want the script to report the value if it exists or report `None` if the key has no value.

I do this for a number of key value pairs and they all work except one.

These key/value pairs report `None` if there is no value for the key:

```
instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
    for reservation in instance_list["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation.get("Instances", []):
            if instance['PublicDnsName']:
                public_dns_name = instance['PublicDnsName']
            else:
                public_dns_name = None
            if 'KeyName' in instance:
                key_name = instance['KeyName']
            else:
                key_name = None
```

This one always shows a blank value instead of `None`. It does report a value when they key has a value:

```
                if 'PrivateDnsName' in instance:
                    private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName']
                else:
                    private_dns = None
```

Here is the value of `instance` for an instance ID that shows a blank entry for `private_dns`:

```
{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-062f7200baf2fa504', 'InstanceId': 'i-02fa5c552a10ddfca', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'KeyName': 'sncr-timd', 'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 22, 25, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Monitoring': {'State': 'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1b', 'GroupName': '', 'Tenancy': 'default'}, 'PrivateDnsName': '', 'ProductCodes': [], 'PublicDnsName': '', 'State': {'Code': 48, 'Name': 'terminated'}, 'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2020-01-15 14:43:16 GMT)', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [], 'ClientToken': '', 'EbsOptimized': False, 'EnaSupport': True, 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'NetworkInterfaces': [], 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'SecurityGroups': [], 'StateReason': {'Code': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown', 'Message': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown'}, 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 'CpuOptions': {'CoreCount': 1, 'ThreadsPerCore': 1}, 'CapacityReservationSpecification': {'CapacityReservationPreference': 'open'}, 'HibernationOptions': {'Configured': False}, 'MetadataOptions': {'State': 'pending', 'HttpTokens': 'optional', 'HttpPutResponseHopLimit': 1, 'HttpEndpoint': 'enabled'}}
```

This is how the output looks when the `instance` does have a `private_dns` key and value:

```
Private DNS: ip-172-31-37-19.us-east-2.compute.internal
```

This is how an `instance` looks when `private_dns` exists:

```
{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-02ccb28830b645a41', 'InstanceId': 'i-069e87e16db1bf49b', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'KeyName': 'sncr-timd', 'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 22, 27, 17, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Monitoring': {'State': 'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-2c', 'GroupName': '', 'Tenancy': 'default'}, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-37-19.us-east-2.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.37.19', 'ProductCodes': [], 'PublicDnsName': 'ec2-18-223-15-106.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'PublicIpAddress': '18.223.15.106', 'State': {'Code': 16, 'Name': 'running'}, 'StateTransitionReason': '', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-22038f6e', 'VpcId': 'vpc-859c5aee', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 22, 27, 18, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-08f30292b9a7039bc'}}], 'ClientToken': '', 'EbsOptimized': False, 'EnaSupport': True, 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'NetworkInterfaces': [{'Association': {'IpOwnerId': 'amazon', 'PublicDnsName': 'ec2-18-223-15-106.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'PublicIp': '18.223.15.106'}, 'Attachment': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 14, 22, 27, 17, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-0937973380674deef', 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'DeviceIndex': 0, 'Status': 'attached'}, 'Description': '', 'Groups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-1', 'GroupId': 'sg-08b8c8a89bcc3c692'}], 'Ipv6Addresses': [], 'MacAddress': '0a:d9:9b:03:a7:a8', 'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-0bfcd12253ecf87ec', 'OwnerId': '565241749827', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-37-19.us-east-2.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.37.19', 'PrivateIpAddresses': [{'Association': {'IpOwnerId': 'amazon', 'PublicDnsName': 'ec2-18-223-15-106.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'PublicIp': '18.223.15.106'}, 'Primary': True, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-37-19.us-east-2.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.37.19'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'Status': 'in-use', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-22038f6e', 'VpcId': 'vpc-859c5aee', 'InterfaceType': 'interface'}], 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'SecurityGroups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-1', 'GroupId': 'sg-08b8c8a89bcc3c692'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 'CpuOptions': {'CoreCount': 1, 'ThreadsPerCore': 1}, 'CapacityReservationSpecification': {'CapacityReservationPreference': 'open'}, 'HibernationOptions': {'Configured': False}, 'MetadataOptions': {'State': 'applied', 'HttpTokens': 'optional', 'HttpPutResponseHopLimit': 1, 'HttpEndpoint': 'enabled'}}
```

I'm wondering why that is. How do I correct that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think key `PrivateDnsName` always axists, try changing:

```
private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName']
```

with

```
private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName'] if instance['PrivateDnsName'] else None
```

**EDIT**

To avoid possible `KeyError` you can use `.get()`

```
vpc_id = instance.get('VpcId') if instance.get('VpcId') else None
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Any idea why that works and the version I had does not? That format does work for the other key/valu pairs that I have.

Comment: @bluethundr this should work for the other key/value. This is due to `PrivateDnsName` is always preset in `instance` with a blank value, so your condition is only evaluating if key exists, not its value, my answer evaluate both.

Comment: This worked for all my key/value pairs except one. I tried getting `vpc_id = instance['VpcId'] if instance['VpcId'] else None` to replace `if 'VpcId' in instance:
                        vpc_id = instance['VpcId']
                    else:
                        vpc_id = None` and instead it gives an error: `An exception has occurred: 'VpcId'` (I have this in a `try` block). What's wrong with the way I wrote this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's because some `instance` has an empty string stored in the `"PrivateDnsName"` `key`. Try replacing:

```
if 'PrivateDnsName' in instance:
    private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName']
else:
    private_dns = None
```

With:

```
if 'PrivateDnsName' in instance and instance['PrivateDnsName'] != '':
    private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName']
else:
    private_dns = None
```